# Comparision directly on null value safe?

Tags: apex, null-pointer, null

So many times, we do a null check of a field value and then compare them

```
boolean checkAmountGreaterThan10k(Opportunity record){
    if(record.Amount!=null){
       return record.Amount > 10000;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then I recently discovered that any comparison operation performed on null value returns false.

Something like :

```
Integer bla = null;
System.debug(bla > 10000);//Prints 'false'
System.debug(bla >= 10000);//Prints 'false'
System.debug(bla < 10000);//Prints 'false'
System.debug(bla <= 10000);//Prints 'false'

System.debug( bla + 10000); // throws Null Ptr Exception
```

Thus I was thinking to use this in the above `checkAmountGreaterThan10k` as

```
boolean checkAmountGreaterThan10k(Opportunity record){  
       return record.Amount > 10000;    
}
```

Is this a documented behavior of comparison operator involving null, I was thinking about saving many lines of code with this.

I came from java world where I used to check null every time, similar java equivalent code throws NullPtrException

```
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        Integer i = null ;
        System.out.println(i < 20); //Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException,
    }
}
```

[Java code link:](https://ideone.com/HcCjTv)

Is the Apex Runtime not throwing a null ptr exception in Apex a bug or undocumented feature?

Comment: Numeric comparison against false used to throw NPE, I am 100% certain. Interesting that they would make this change and not announce it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find this behavior documented in the Apex Developer Guide's [Expression Operators](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_expressions_operators_understanding.htm) for the comparison operators:

- Less than operator
- Greater than operator
- Less than or equal to operator
- Greater than or equal to operator.

> If `x` or `y` equal `null` and are Integers, Doubles, Dates, or Datetimes, the expression is **false**.

Comment: Ah nice...  awesome that I can use it without worrying

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly (to me), this behavior is [documented](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_expressions_operators_understanding.htm). I have pasted the reference for **`<`**, but the same statement is made for **`<=`**, **`>`**, and **`>=`**.

> **Operator** 
>   `<`
>
> **Syntax**
>   `x < y`
>
> **Description**
>   Less than operator. If x is less than y, the expression evaluates to true. Otherwise, the expression evaluates to false.
>   Note:
>
> - Unlike other database stored procedures, Apex does not support tri-state Boolean logic, and the comparison of any two values can never result in null.
> - **If x or y equal null and are Integers, Doubles, Dates, or Datetimes, the expression is false.**
> - A non-null String or ID value is always greater than a null value.
> - If x and y are IDs, they must reference the same type of object. Otherwise, a runtime error results.
> - If x or y is an ID and the other value is a String, the String value is validated and treated as an ID.
> - x and y cannot be Booleans.
> - The comparison of two strings is performed according to the locale of the context user and is case-insensitive.

---

On the contrary, the following operators note

> **x and y cannot be null**

- **`+=`**
- **`*=`**
- **`-=`**
- **`/=`**
- **`|=`**
- **`&=`**
- **`&&`**
- **`||`**

Surprisingly, this indication is not made for arithmetic operations, even though it still holds.